# modRewrite RewriteCond to turn off ssl redirect for a certain requested URL

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

In my website mycreditstatus.co.za, I use .htaccess to rewrite and redirect a URL from http to https and here's the code I use for the .htaccess in the public_html (http) directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It works just fine but it rewrites and redirects all http urls into https.

The problem is that my website also performs some requests to non-https sites so I don't want to rewrite and redirect some of the links to https.

Here's one of the links that I don't want to redirect/rewrite:

http://imupost.co.za/

I want to know the code that I should write for the .htaccess on the public_ssl (https) directory since the request will be coming from there.

Comment: You can use a exclude under `RewriteCond`

Comment: I don't know how to exclude the url. Using modRewrite is quite new to me. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this code in .htaccess under your public_html dir:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^imupost\.co\.za$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And have this code in .htaccess under your public_ssl dir:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imupost\.co\.za$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just a little question on your code, why do you add backslashes before dots ?

Comment: @LucasWillems: Because this is a regular expression where dot means any character. So in theory regex `imupost.co.za` can match `imupost:co-za` also which we don't want. In any regex dots needs to be escaped.

Comment: @anubhava: The code still redirects imupost.co.za to https. :(

Comment: @maikelsabido: Pls test in a different browser or clear your browser cache.

Comment: @maikelsabido: I have opened http://imupost.co.za in 2 browsers and both times it did NOT switch to https.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes but it's not my concern. My website mycreditstatus.co.za should send some parameters to imupost (http) but somehow, it changes the http to https.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `My website mycreditstatus.co.za should send some parameters to imupost (http)` ?

Comment: Also looks like you didn't follow my suggestion completely. In my answer I also have this: **`And have this code in .htaccess under your public_ssl dir:`**

Comment: I mean I have a main website w/c is mycreditstatus.co.za and this website sends requests to imupost.co.za (http), but somehow, instead of sending it to http, it changes the http to https that's why I want to perform modrewrite to redirect it to the correct url.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion. but I put it in the mycreditstatus directory (public_html and public_ssl).

Comment: 1. No you don't have at correct place since `https://imupost.co.za/` stays like that but it should switch to: `http://imupost.co.za/` 2: How is `mycreditstatus.co.za` sending request to `imupost.co.za`? Do you have any link or form submit on `mycreditstatus.co.za` ?

Comment: Oh, okay, so I should put the code in the imupost directories? Yes there's a form that submits parameters via POST method.

Comment: Yes later code needs to be in imupost's HTTPS DOCUMENT_ROOT. However just to let you know posting to a http URL from HTTPS isn't going to work even with all the mod_rewrite stuff since mod_rewrite will redirect but POST data will not be transferred. GET info is fine.

Comment: Oh... Okay. thanks for all the help. I'll try to put the code in the https document root.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^imupost.co.za$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Comment: And try this without the third line. What do you want to say by "the code but it still did not work" ? Is there an error or just there are no redirections ?

Comment: Okay I'll try it without the third line. What I meant was, it was still redirecting to (https://)imupost.co.za

Comment: But it's not what you want ? You said that you want to redirect http to https and the code do that...

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear. I have a website mycreditstatus.co.za and it is an https site. It should send requests to other urls like http://imupost.co.za but what it does is, it changes the http to https, I want to remove https redirection to imupost.co.za only.